# Query Result as Datasource for ComboBox (VB.Net)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox

I have two Comboboxes and a DataGridView. the first ComboBox looks at column of the DataGridView for its values. I need the second ComboBox to look at the value of the first and then get the values from the table filtered by the Value of the first ComboBox.

I get the information for the first ComboBox like this: (This runs on the "Form Load" Event)

```
    With FItemTypeComboBox
        .DataSource = DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems
        .ValueMember = "fItemType"
    End With
```

For the second ComboBox's Datasource, I want to run a query that functions something like:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT fItemName FROM tblItems
    WHERE "fItemType" = FItemTypeComboBox.Text
```

But I don't know where or how to implement this.

I have tried the following, but no matter what variation I run, it always fails:

```
Private Sub FItemNameComboBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FItemNameComboBox.Enter

    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("tblItems")

    table.Columns.Add("fItemType")
    table.Columns.Add("fItemName")

    Dim Result() As DataRow = table.Select("fItemType" = FItemTypeComboBox.Text)

    With FItemNameComboBox
        .DataSource = Result
        .ValueMember = Result.ToString
    End With

End Sub
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and (obviously) Visual Basic.

Comment: What is the data type of the returned linq query?

Comment: They are all standard Strings. Basically I am looking to filter a large table into categories, then select an item from that category and add it to a different table.

Comment: I would like to know the _exact_ data type. Is it a String(), IEnumerable(Of String), IList(Of String)? :)

Comment: I don't know. The table that is used in DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems lists fItemType as nvarchar(MAX), Does that help?

Comment: Doesn't IntelliSense show you the type? Example: `Dim result As Object = (From row As DataRow In table Where row.Field(Of Integer)("id") = 1 Select row)`. If I hover the mouse over the first **(** in `Dim result As Object = (...` I see that the returned result is `EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)`.

Comment: When I hover over the ( in my code, It returns "Public Function Select(filterExpression As String) As System.Data.DataRow()

Comment: I'm a bit confused . Is the problem querying for data or populating the query result into a ComboBox?

Comment: Apparently Both. I am relatively New to VB.Net, and I am getting lost on the most basic of issues. I can properly Add items to the Table, and then Select the items in the first ComboBox, but I cannot populate the second. I don't know if I need a separate query, or if I can do it all with code, or what. I am sorry I can't explain more what I need to do.

Comment: Okey, give me some minutes and I'll make you an example.

Comment: First thing that jumps out is this should be
table.Select("fItemType  = '" & FItemTypeComboBox.Text & "'")

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I got busy. Check the answer I've posted. I didn't got time to test it though.

Comment: It worked just fine. I am taking your code and modifying it for another area of my form as well. This is great, and I have marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
A DataView act like a wrapper for a DataTable, supporting editing, filtering and sorting.

```
Private Sub FItemTypeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FItemTypeComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim selected As Object = Me.FItemTypeComboBox.SelectedItem

    If (TypeOf selected Is DataRowView) Then

        Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(selected, DataRowView).Row
        Dim fItemType As String = CStr(row.Item("fItemType"))
        Dim view As New DataView(DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems)

        view.RowFilter = String.Format("[fItemType]='{0}'", fItemType)

        Me.FItemNameComboBox.DataSource = view.ToTable(True, "fItemName")
        Me.FItemNameComboBox.DisplayMember = "fItemName"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked very well. Now I have another issue, but I suspect it may be because of how I added the ComboBox to the Form originally. If I add a row to my table manually, then attempt to change the selection in fItemTypeComboBox, it actually changes the value of that column in the selected row, instead of just selecting that value. EDIT: Nevermind, I removed the ComboBox and added it from the ToolBox as an unbound one and it seems to work fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: Every changes made in `tblItems` will be reflected in `FItemTypeComboBox`. It is binded to that instance. You could copy the table by calling `tblItems.Copy()` and use this as datasource.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do that. I understand WHAT you want me to do, but I don't know the code to implement it. I'm sorry. Can you explain a bit more?